# Whether to give credit/attribute or not for pixbay.com images ?

Tags: copyright, licensing, creative-commons

I am making some training videos to teach some concept of computer for commercial purpose means,  I might be sell these videos in future.

In these videos, I have used the images which I have downloaded from pixbay.com

I want to know whether, attribute  or credit has to give for those images which I have used in my video ?

here is the [link](https://pixabay.com/en/service/terms/#usage) , where they have mentioned the rules which have to follow to use the images.

I have gone through the this link, most of the rules I have understood, 
but still I want expert advice , to know whether I have to give attributes or credits of those images which I have used in videos. ?

Comment: What exactly do you wonder? The linked ToS says: "You are free to adapt and use them for commercial purposes **without attributing** the original author or source." (bold emphasis mine)

Comment: @unor - that sounds like an answer. We don't answer in comments.

Comment: @DaleM: Okay, I gave it a shot. I commented because I wondered if there’s something more behind the question.

Answer (score 1):

Pixabay’s *Terms of Service* say about [Using Images and Videos](https://pixabay.com/en/service/terms/#usage) (bold emphasis mine):

> You are free to adapt and use them for commercial purposes **without attributing** the original author or source.

In the same section they say that the images and videos "are released under [Creative Commons CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/deed.en)". This is Creative Commons’ "Public Domain Dedication", which is a way to release something into the [public domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain), and for jurisdictions that don’t know the public domain concept, to release it under something that comes as close as possible to this ("to the extent allowed by law").

From this deed follows that you are allowed to do anything with the work (even [licensing it under some other license](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1386/138)), without *having* to do something (like providing attribution, or even stating that the work is released under CC0). But note that [trademark and patent rights are not affected](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC0_FAQ#What_about_other_IP_related_rights.2C_such_as_trademark_and_patent_rights.3F) by this.

That said, all this is only the case if the original author (or copyright holder) *actually* released it under CC0 (or into the public domain via some other way). The risk is (like always with such sites) that the person who uploaded the work to Pixabay hadn’t the right to release it under CC0, in which case neither Pixabay nor you have the right to use it as such.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Can I get copyright of the videos, in which I have used these images ?

Comment: @bnil: Yes, if the image is released into the public domain (e.g., under CC0), then you can use this image in your video, for which the default copyright laws apply (as if it was your image to begin with).

Comment: Thanks a lot , do you have any idea, whether I have to give the links of the images while submitting the videos for copyright process ?

Comment: @bnil: Sorry, no -- I didn’t even know that there is a "copyright process" where you submit the video. In m experience, you just create the video and publish it, the copyright is automatically yours.